# Сопоставление шаблонов для очереди на основе Seq (Data.Sequence)

Tags: очередь, haskell, сопоставление-с-образцом

Создаем тип очереди на основе `Seq`:

```
import Data.Sequence

type Queue v = Seq v
```

теперь хочу написать функцию, возвращающую первый элемент очереди ("голову"). Казалось бы, из всего, что прочитал и нагуглил должно быть что-то **вроде**:

```
qhead :: Queue v -> v
qhead Empty = error "empty sequence"
qhead (x :<| xs) = x
```

Сыпит:

> Not in scope: data constructor ‘:<|’

Ну, ладно, исхитрился так:

```
qhead' :: ViewL v -> v
qhead' EmptyL = error "empty sequence"
qhead' (x :< xs) = x

qhead :: Queue v -> v
qhead q = qhead' $ viewl q
```

Но может как-нибудь более уклюже возможно сделать? Непосредственно с типом `Queue` сопоставить, без посредничества какого-то там дурацкого `ViewL`? Или так кошерно?

Полный код:

```
import Data.Sequence

type Queue v = Seq v

qhead' :: ViewL v -> v
qhead' EmptyL = error "empty sequence"
qhead' (x :< xs) = x

qhead :: Queue v -> v
qhead q = qhead' $ viewl q

{-
*R.QTree> qhead $ fromList [12,13,14,15]
12
-}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что ваша проблема в том, что `:<|` - это не конструктор, а pattern synonym. Не могу утверждать этого с уверенностью, потому что не вижу всего вашего проекта. У вас включено расширение `PatternSynonyms`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Да, я видел в примерах, что включено, но предпочитаю делать проект без расширений (по глупому перфекцианизму) поэтому не настаиваю, чтобы сделать сопоставление шаблонов именно с помощью `:<|`, просто чтобы pattern matching напрямую работал с `Seq` - неужели я хочу слишком многого? ;)

Comment: Ок, написал ответ.

Comment: Можете использовать полностью стандартный (в рамках Haskell 2010, надеюсь хотя бы это не проблема) код `qhead q | x :< _ <- viewl q = x` или в конце концов `qhead q = let x :< _ = viewl q in x`. Вы хотите использовать конструкции, не предусмотренные базовым языком, при этом не хотите использовать расширения, так что да - вы хотите слишком многого.

Comment: @extrn Спасибо за ваш полезный комментарий! 

Хотя я против священых войн, но тут вынужден заметить, что идея использования Очередей (типа `Seq`) в таком же стиле, как использование стандартных списков `[]` (т.е. с сопоставлением шаблонов) без дополнительных танцев с бубном выглядит достаточно естественно и ожидаемо. Ведь я полюбил Haskell за его простоту и лаконичность, а использование расширений для такой очевидной вещи выглядит ИМХО костылями и сбокуприпеком. Вопрос даже не к языку, а ИМХО к разработчикам типа `Seq` - надо было сделать соответствующий конструктор, что, сложно было что-ли?

Comment: Простота всегда предпочтительна, но не все структуры данных просты во внутренней реализации. `Seq`, `Set`, `Map`, `Vector`, `Array` и многие многие другие типы данных с внутренней структурой значительно сложнее чем у `[]` не выставляют свои конструкторы напоказ именно для того, чтобы сохранить простоту и абстрактность. Да даже `Integer` (в отличие от `Int`) это сложная структура данных, к которой вы доступа не имеете. Поэтому каждый компилятор волен реализовывать ее по своему, оставляя вам только методы работы с типом, не позволяя вашему коду привязываться к деталям реализации.

Comment: Также добавлю к комментарию @extrn, что новые возможности языка (такие как, в данном случае, pattern synonyms) были добавлены _именно для того_, чтобы обеспечить простоту и лаконичность в нетривиальных случаях, и библиотека `Data.Sequence` успешно ими пользуется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно вашему комментарию, у вас отключено расширение `PatternSynonyms`.

Библиотека `Data.Sequence` не экспортирует конструкторы для типа `Seq`, только синонимы. Это значит, что без поддержки синонимов вы не сможете сопостовлять шаблоны с этим типом. Просто нечего сопоставлять. Поэтому вам придётся или включить поддержку синонимов, или пользоваться некрасивыми обходными манёврами.

---

Мне кажется, что ваше неприятие расширений основано не их недопонимании. Расширения языка в Haskell - это не дополнительные библиотеки и не вошебные хаки. Они - такая же часть языка, как и всё остальное.

Они сделаны отключаемыми только для того, чтобы не заставлять людей постоянно переписывать старый код. Некоторые расширения чуть меняют смысл существующих конструкций, некоторые требуют дополнительных пояснений, и т.п. Если эти возможности просто тупо добавить в язык (как это делают почти все остальные языки), то при каждом обновлении компилятора придётся чинить развалившийся код. Чтобы этого не случилось, Haskell заранее принял решение включать новые возможности "по требованию".

Повторю ещё раз: вышеописанная логика применима только к уже существующим проектам. Если у вас уже есть куча кода, написанного пять лет назад, то вы можете пользоваться современным компилятором, просто не включайте новые расширения.

Но для совершенно нового кода не включать расширения нет никакого смысла: вы просто без всякой причины заставляете себя писать на языке десятилетней давности, вот и всё. Никакого выигрыша от этого.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Хочу только сделать пояснение. Я не питаю особой ненависти к расширением, но Haskell мне нравится именно своей абстрактной красотой и однородностью идей. Не с практической точки зрения (хотя, не спорю, может быть использован и в практических целях), я даже вписал в резюме навык Haskell в раздел Хобби, а не в скиллы. С этой (и только этой!) точки зрения мне бы не хотелось превращения дивно-прекрасного языка в практически-пригодное подобие C#. Не сочтите этот комментарий за троллинг, это только мое скромное мнение.

Comment: да, `PatternSynonyms` лучшее решение в данном случае